# Integrating Office and OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, lumia-925, office

What's the easiest way to use my outlook account on my windows Nokia lumia 925 so I can type on my phone and it saves to a document on my OneDrive? How do I create a new document on my phone with either Office or OneDrive?

Comment: You may also want to check out OneNote for this purpose. I like it for quick notes, and it has its own web interface that I find more useful for seeing, categorizing, and moving between my notes.

Comment: I do use OneNote a ton but I want to be able to work on a paper when I don't have a computer. @TylerJamesYoung

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office on Windows Phone will be automatically connected to the OneDrive that belongs to your primary Microsft Account (the same one you use for store downloads).

To change where a document should be saved simply create a new document -> then open the app bar at the bottom -> select "save to..." and choose phone or OneDrive. If you choose to store the file in the cloud, it will be automatically synced to your phone when you open it.

Comment: Can this new document be created from the phone? If so would it be created from Office? I'm just a little new to this and confused thanks

Comment: @Jeff it is as simple as going into the "Office" app on your phone, and tapping the `+` button to create the new document, which you can then happily edit.